# Mouse Hover in VueJS component implementation in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

My Mouse hover is not working when I am using it on Laravel.

My Vue file is stored in `resources/js/Dashboard.vue`

What I tried so far is to change `v-on:mouseover` with `@mouseover` but it still not working.

The Result is that when I hover the button it doesn't change texts.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Below, the content of my `Dashboard.vue` file;

```
<template>
<div id="mouse">
  <a
    v-on:mouseover="mouseover"
    v-on:mouseleave="mouseleave">
    {{message}}
  </a>
</div>
</template>
<!--Force Override of the css style for datepicker class-->

<style>

  #mouse {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: block;
    width: 280px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background: #007db9;
  }
</style>

<script>

export default {
    components: {
    },
    data() {
        return {
          showAudience: false,
          message: 'Hover Me',
        }
    },
    computed: {
    },
    methods : {
    mouseover: function(){
      this.message = 'Good!'
    },    
    mouseleave: function(){
      this.message = 'Hover Me!'
    }
    },
    mounted() {
    },
}
</script>
```

Here, the content of my `Blade.php` file;

```
@extends('layouts.app', ['pageSlug' => 'dashboard'])

@section('content')
  <dashboard-component></dashboard-component>
  @endsection

@push('js')
    <script src="{{ asset('black') }}/js/plugins/chartjs.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          //demo.initDashboardPageCharts();
        });
    </script>
@endpush
```

To take a close look and reproduce locally, below is the `package.json` file;

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue": "^2.6.10",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
        "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "npm:@soda/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@^1.7.1",
        "vue-chartjs": "^3.4.2",
        "vue2-datepicker": "^2.12.0"
    }
}
```

Edit added my app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './components/App.vue'

/**
 * The following block of code may be used to automatically register your
 * Vue components. It will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
 * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
 *
 * Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>
 */

// const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i);
// files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default));
Vue.component('dashboard-component', require('./components/Dashboard.vue').default);
Vue.component('base-table', require('./components/base/BaseTable.vue'));

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);


new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but did you add your javascript files to webpack & run `npm run dev`

Comment: I would always execute npm run dev whenever i change something in my vue files

Comment: and my webpack.mix.js already contains mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

Comment: Okay, it was just a quick thought, since I forgot about these little things all the time. Did you check your console logs, any errors there? Might as well add some simple console.log inside your script, to see if it even initializes. One more suggestion, if you're using google chrome, there's a nice vue.js extension for easier preview and debugging.

Comment: theres no error in console log sadly. :( and i really dont know what else i can do or what else i need to do. Its just a simple code and i don't know what i'm doing wrong

Comment: Try and inspect the element in your browsers console and see if it has the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` [events attached](https://imgur.com/a/9MQSrBF)

Comment: From what I can tell, you haven't bound your Vue instance to a DOM element. Am I wrong?

Comment: I dont think that i did that, how can i do that? Sorry im pretty much new to this thing

Comment: Is it possible that the element is behind something else? Try dropping in the CSS `:hover { outline: 2px dotted #f00; }` so you can see exactly which elements your mouse is over.

Comment: when i used that css. It shows the dotted red borders when i hover so i don't think so

Comment: What if you try v-bind:mouseover="mouseover" instead of v-on:mouseover="mouseover" ?

Comment: Does your component render correctly?

Comment: The vue component renders as i can see the button but it seems vue events are not working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that i should put

```
script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

in resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php instead of putting it in my other view file such as those i manually created. For those wondering where in app.blade.php should i put the code above.Put it at the end of the body tag

For example in app.blade.php

```
<body>
 // some code here
 // some code there


// put the script code here
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these to prevent default event and propagation

```
v-on:mouseover.prevent.stop="mouseover"
v-on:mouseleave.prevent.stop="mouseleave"
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works, When i run on my system it works.

I tried it on JSFiddle.

```
//html
<div id="mouse" class="mouse1">
 <a
    v-on:mouseover="mouseover"
    v-on:mouseleave="mouseleave">
    {{name}}
  </a>
</div>
//CSS
#mouse {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: block;
    width: 280px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background: #007db9;
  }

//js 
new Vue({
  el: "#mouse",
  data: {
   name: 'Hover Me!',
     showAudience: false,
  },
  methods : {
    mouseover: function(){
      this.name = 'Good!'
    },    
    mouseleave: function(){
      this.name = 'Hover Me!'
    }
    },
    mounted(){
        }    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Neat. Looks like as the button changes size during the animation, the mouse goes in and out of hover state because the edge is moving.

I added a div around each button, and attached the hover triggers to the divs instead of the buttons

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <h1>Hover the mouse near the border</h1>
        <hr>
        <div @mouseover="hoverOver" @mouseout="hoverOut">
            <button :class="classes">IMMEDIATE</button>
        </div>
        <br><br><br>
        <div @mouseover="hoverOver" @mouseout="hoverOutTimeout">
            <button :class="classes">WAIT JUST A BIT
        </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jmbldwn/kbswLpto/5/

Answer (score 0):

In your `Dashboard.vue` file, try to change below:

```js
data() {
    return {
        showAudience: false,
        message: 'Hover Me',
    }
},
```

Into:

```js
data: {
    showAudience: false,
    message: 'Hover Me',
},
```

(maybe an object works better for you)